# On the proof of "integral does not depend on the values of $f$ at the endpoints of the interval.

Tags: real-analysis

I don't understand the statement from the last paragraph the Theorem 6.19 of the book Advanced Calculus by Fitzpatrick. I would appreciate a clear explanation of the following section:

> But the difference between $U(f, P_n)$ and $U(f, P^*_n)$ is exactly the contributions to $U(f, P_n)$ from the first and last intervals of the partition $P_n$ .

1- What that means at all and how it is concluded from the previous statements?

> Arguing as above, we have $$lim [U(f, P_n)-U(f, P^*_n)] = 0.$$

2- Same question as question 1.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $P_n^* \subset P_n$. The upper sums agree on all subintervals of $P_n^*$, leaving contributions from the first and last subintervals of $P_n$ in the difference.

Hence,

$$U(f,P_n) = \sup_{x \in [a,a_n]} f(x) (a_n-a) + U(f,P_n^*) + \sup_{x \in [b_n,b]} f(x)(b-b_n),$$

and

$$0 \leqslant |U(f,P_n^*)-U(f,P_n)|= |\sup_{x \in [a,a_n]} f(x) (a_n-a)+ \sup_{x \in [b_n,b]} f(x)(b-b_n)|\\\leqslant M(a_n-a) + M (b-b_n)\\ \to_{ n \to \infty} 0$$